# Under what circumstances would System.Windows.Media.Transform.Inverse return null

Tags: wpf, transform

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.transform.inverse) of `System.Windows.Media.Transform.Inverse`, the function

> Gets the inverse of this transform, if it exists.

But not much further explanation, there.  So when would the inverse ***not*** exist?  Under what circumstances or types of transforms?

I use a TransformGroup that has both a TranslateTransform and RotateTransform which I modify individually.  Do I need to worry about it returning null for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are technical ways to describe non-invertible transformation. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Groups. But intuitively, it's easy to see that, given that a transform can be represented as a matrix, and given that the inverse of a transform matrix is the matrix that multiplied by the original transform matrix gives you the identity matrix, that it's going to come down to the mathematical operations of division and multiplication.

In particular, just as I can provide the multiplicative inverse of any scalar except zero, simply by dividing the multiplicative identity (i.e. `1`) by that number, likewise I can provide the multiplicative inverse of any matrix that doesn't require dividing by zero when I "divide" the identity by that matrix.

Geometrically, this fails (i.e. dividing by zero would occur) if your transform somehow causes the transformed geometry to have a non-zero length in some dimension.

From that, we can see that if you use a scaling transform where the scale factor is zero in at least one axis, that transform will be non-invertible.

And indeed:

```
GeneralTransform t = new ScaleTransform(1, 0).Inverse;
```

Returns `null`.

Do you need to worry about it? I don't know. That depends on how you're creating your transforms in the first place. That detail isn't present in your question.

Typically, I don't think it's something you'd need to think about. But if you're in a situation where for whatever reason a transform's scale factor winds up at zero, either through user input (whether entered numerically or through dragging the size of some shape on screen), successively combining fractional scale factors, etc. then sure, it's theoretically possible you could find yourself with a non-invertible transform.

If it were me, unless I could prove with certainty that I'm not doing anything with the transforms that would cause it to be non-invertible, I would go ahead and make sure I handle the `null` result in some reasonable way. This could either be to change the preconditions to create that certainty, or maybe you allow it and then just not do anything with the inverted transform if it's not invertible (since if it's not, there's probably no reasonable on-screen rendering that would make any sense anyway, that seems like a reasonable approach).

Comment: Wow that was an excellent answer.   Much appreciated.  Particularly since there is nothing about matrix math has ever been "intuitive" for me!